# Azure B2C Terms of Service flow - storing the text and legally verifiable user agreement

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Is there any built-in mechanism in Azure B2C for storing the text of the Terms of Service along with an evidence on which text the user agreed when signed-up?

There is a Custom policy example for Terms of Service, but it seems it only provides an UI with a check box without storing or displaying the text of the service terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way for AAD B2C to store a TOU against the User object attribute, unless it is within 256 char, which I expect it will not be.

Rather, you can use a sample like [this](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/sign-in-sign-up-versioned-tou) which presents a checkbox, and writes the *version* of the TOU that was presented.

The TOU needs to be offered up by your [HTML customisation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html), or you can write it in a `paragraph` [claim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claimsschema#userinputtype).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.